# Error while Inserting data in loop pne by one using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

while inserting records in a loop 
The property "id" is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

```
 secProductionRepository.Add(tblSecProduction);
 this.SaveChanges();
```

CODE

Controller : This is the Controller code from  where i am calling method of Repository .   Adding data into repository and calling function to insert. i think i have to initialize it every time with new keyword. But where should i do that.

```
SingleMaster objGetXMLData = _iSingleService.GetXMLData();
if (objGetXMLData._tblSecDoorXMLData != null)
{
    for (int totalCount = 0; totalCount < objGetXMLData._tblSecDoorXMLData.Count; totalCount++)
    {
        _tblSecDoorsProduction.txtTongue = singleDoorModel.txtTongue;
        _tblSecDoorsProduction.numFibMesh = Convert.ToInt32(singleDoorModel.chkBoxFibreMesh);
        _tblSecDoorsProduction.dteDesDate = DateTime.Now;
        _iSingleDoorService.UpdatetblSecDoorsProduction(_tblSecDoorsProduction, "Insert");
    }
}
```

Repository :  Here i am inserting new row into the table

```
public void UpdatetblSecDoorsProduction(tblSecDoorsProduction  tblSecDoorsProduction, string Message)
{
    var secDoorsProductionRepository =   Nuow.Repository<tblSecDoorsProduction>();
    tblSecDoorsProduction alreadyAttached = null;
    if (Message == "Insert")
    {
        secDoorsProductionRepository.Add(tblSecDoorsProduction);
        Nuow.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show whole code?

Comment: var secDoorsProductionRepository =              Nuow.Repository<tblSecDoorsProduction>();
   secDoorsProductionRepository.Add(tblSecDoorsProduction); Nuow.SaveChanges();

Comment: Could you show the whole code, as dawidr already mentioned? Where is the Loop? Are you creating a new repository in the Loop? We can't see anything :-D

Comment: More code:) Update you question with whole method.

Comment: After insering one record, When it comes to next it throws error
   Something Like this

Comment: for (int totalCount = 0; totalCount <    objGetXMLData._tblSecDoorXMLData.Count; totalCount++)
                    {
   _iSingleDoorService.UpdatetblSecDoorsProduction(_tblSecDoorsProduction, "Insert");

     }

Comment: No not creating new repository in loop
But calling repository from controller to insert data

Comment: Can you please update you question with code of WHOLE method. You are posting fragments of code here and there and it's hard to read.

Comment: Updated the question,  Please heck now

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: The property "id" is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new object each time in the loop. Updated code here:

```
for (int totalCount = 0; totalCount < objGetXMLData._tblSecDoorXMLData.Count; totalCount++)
{
    tblSecDoorsProduction _tblSecDoorsProduction = new tblSecDoorsProduction();
    _tblSecDoorsProduction.txtTongue = singleDoorModel.txtTongue;
    _tblSecDoorsProduction.numFibMesh = Convert.ToInt32(singleDoorModel.chkBoxFibreMesh);
    _tblSecDoorsProduction.dteDesDate = DateTime.Now;
    _iSingleDoorService.UpdatetblSecDoorsProduction(_tblSecDoorsProduction, "Insert");
}
```

Comment: Thanks dawidr .. worked for me. I had created object outside loop.